# AJAX/JSON populate dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax

I am making ajax call using ASP.NET 3.5 to populate dropdown list as a part of cascading dropdowns, and it works fine, I am getting JSON formatted results back. But I have no luck populating dropdown calling this function:

```
$.fn.populateSelect = function(data)
{
     if( data.length > 0)
     {
          var dropDown = this;

          dropDown.empty().append('<option selected = "selected" value="0">(Select Item)</option>');
          $.each(data, function()
          {
                dropDown.append($("<option></option>").val(this.Key).text(this.Value));


          });

      }
```

}

Always gives "Object doesn't support this property or method" on a last line. Data that I am getting back from AJAX call, which is a C# serialized List of KeyValuePairs typically looks like this:

```
[{"Key":1,"Value":"Anchor Fixation"},{"Key":3,"Value":"Ankle Arthroplasty"},{"Key":19,"Value":"Disc Arthroplasty"},{"Key":20,"Value":"Elbow Arthroplasty, "},{"Key":23,"Value":"Fracture Fixation/ Bone Fixation"},{"Key":32,"Value":"Hip Arthroplasty,"},{"Key":38,"Value":"Knee Arthroplasty"},{"Key":55,"Value":"Radial Head Arthroplasty"},{"Key":59,"Value":"Screw/Rod/Wire/Pin"},{"Key":60,"Value":"Shoulder Arthroplasty"},{"Key":61,"Value":"Silastic Implant"},{"Key":65,"Value":"Spine fusion/fixation"},{"Key":74,"Value":"Wrist Arthroplasty"}]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer

---

If its ASP.NET 3.5 then the response will be surely wrapped in "d". So try something like this.

```
$.fn.populateSelect = function (msg) {
    var data = msg.hasOwnProperty('d') ? msg.d : msg;
    if (data.length > 0) {
        var output = [];
        output.push('<option selected = "selected" value="0">(Select Item)</option>');
        $.each(data, function (idx, val) {
            output.push('<option value="' + val.Key + '">' + val.Value + '</option>');
        });
        $(this).html(output.join(''));
    }
}
```

Have changed `this` inside `jQuery.each`.
This is more optimal. Because in your method, you were manipulating DOM for adding each `option`.
Now, call it like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var values = [{ "Key": 1, "Value": "Anchor Fixation" }, { "Key": 3, "Value": "Ankle Arthroplasty" }, { "Key": 19, "Value": "Disc Arthroplasty"}];
    $("#myselect").populateSelect(values);
});
```

I dont see why this won't work for you. [Click here to see the **updated** working example](http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/cL8hT/1/).
Is that a browser specific issue?

Comment: Thanks for reply. It didn't solve the problem, since 'data' variable already getting correct value, but 'this' looks like is a 'Browser' instance, which is totally unexpected.

Comment: @Victor: Updated answer. Check it out.

Comment: This didn't give me any errors any more, but here's a mystery - 'Key' and 'Value' added are all 'undefined'. I am using IE7 don't think it's a cross-browser issue

Comment: oh IE7? Was testing at webkit/mozilla. seems like IE is forgetting js is block scoped. i dont have ie7 and ie9 works fine. try the updated populateSelect plugin and jsfiddle

Comment: That's what I tried - your version of populate. What puzzles me is that 'data' variable, or 'msg' look fine, but all this.Key and this.Value all undefined and also their count is wrong, so all I get is a bunch of 'undefined' elemens in my dropdown:-)

Comment: jsfiddle example is working or me, here I am getting "Key is undefined" error, and "val" is 'undefined'

Comment: Thanks, I got this logic worked out. Btw how would you make those newly loaded items visible on a server side so I can save a page?

Comment: Even though the problem was different, but you gave me some useful ideas so I will accept.

Answer (score 0):

Use debugging tool like Firebug and check member variables for dropDown and 'this' where it gives you the error because the error you're getting says that member variable for an object is unknown.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Looks like 'dropDown' is getting correct value, 'this' however is not, looks like it's getting Browser instance, idk why.